# Number of Leap Years within two specific years

Tags: java

I have a small problem. I figured out how to solve this program, but I can't get the output to output ALL the leap years in a table format. Instead, the output shoots out the leap years one at a time, which is something I don't want with my program.

What could be the problem?

EDIT:
**I'm trying to get all the years to pop out using a "JOptionPane" message box (JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ");), but I keep getting only one output per box and many boxes... compared to all the outputs in just one box.**

Here is the code:

```
String enterYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the starting year: \nExample: 2015");   // User enters an input (Year)
    String enterLastYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the ending year: ");

    int i = Integer.parseInt(enterYear);


    if (Integer.parseInt(enterYear) < Integer.parseInt(enterLastYear)){
        for (i = Integer.parseInt(enterYear); i < Integer.parseInt(enterLastYear); i += 4){
            if(i % 400 == 0 || i % 4 == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i + "\n");
            }

        }

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Starting Year is greater than Ending Year!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is your input and the output that you getting?

Comment: @Ambrish, I'm inputting 2000 and 2010, and getting 2004 and 2008. Although I want the years to be outputted in just one box, not multiple boxes. (JOptionPane boxes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Simply need to build the message before passing it to the `JOptionPane`.

Sample Code:

```
public class LeapYearTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LeapYearTest leapYearTest = new LeapYearTest();
        leapYearTest.showLeapYears(2000, 2020);
        leapYearTest.showLeapYears(2000, 2000);
    }

    private void showLeapYears(int start, int end) {
        StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();
        if (start < end) {
            msg.append("<html><table><tr><td><b>Leap Years</b></td></tr>");
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if(i % 400 == 0 || i % 4 == 0) {
                    msg.append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }
            msg.append("</table></html>");
        } else {
            msg.append("Error: Starting Year is greater than Ending Year!");
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg.toString());
    }
}
```

Outputs:
[image: Leap years in table format]
[image: Error message]

Comment: Do you know how you could make that into a tabled format? So it has rows and columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace i += 4 with i++. Also correct formula for leap year is

```
year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0
```

Comment: I still get the same output. Do you know how I would be able to display all the leap years in one 'JOptionPane' popup box?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can apply this logic

```
public void calculateLeapYears(int fromYear,int tillYear){
    int count=0;
        int firstLeapYear;
        if(fromYear% 4==0)
            firstLeapYear=fromYear;
        else
            firstLeapYear=fromYear+(4-fromYear%4);
        for(int i=firstLeapYear;i<=tillYear;i+=4)
            count++;
       System.out.println(count);

}
```